# Behavior of SIGINT with Bash

Tags: linux, bash, sigint

I am running this Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(seq 1 100);
do
    echo $i
    sleep 1
done
```

When I issue `kill -INT <pid>` nothing happens -- the script keeps running. If I issue `kill -TERM <pid>`, the script and the sleep command are both killed. `<pid>` here refers to the PID of the script, not the `sleep` process.

I want to understand what the differences in signal handling here are. I understand issuing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will achieve the same results as sending `-TERM` because of the signal being sent to the process group, but I don't quite understand why issuing `-INT` doesn't behave the same way as issuing `-TERM`. From what I gather the default action of SIGINT is to terminate the process.

**Some context**: My use case is that this script was being started as a subprocess from another program, and that program was sending a `SIGINT` during shutdown, before waiting for X seconds and sending a `SIGKILL`. I changed the `SIGINT` to a `SIGTERM` and it just abruptly killed the process without waiting, and this got me thinking about the behavior difference here.

Comment: I have been reading about how "bash does not forward signals to processes it's waiting on" (including both INT and TERM) but if I change the `sleep 1` to `sleep 10` in my script above and issue `kill -TERM <pid of bash script>` while the sleep is still running, it seems like both the script and sleep will bail out.

Comment: There's a lot of material on this topic all around the internet, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042201/how-does-sigint-relate-to-the-other-termination-signals-such-as-sigterm-sigquit https://mywiki.wooledge.org/SignalTrap#When_is_the_signal_handled.3F Is there anything specific you're looking for? I'm not sure I understand why you're wondering 2 different signals behave differently.

Comment: "why you'r wondering 2 different signals behave differently" -- I am wondering why they behave differently because the default action for both signals is to terminate the program. I'm not registering a trap, so per my understanding they should behave the same. Thank you for the link -- that is what the answer below links.

Answer (score 2):

What you observed is a consequence of an approach called *wait and cooperative exit* (WCE). It's about handling SIGINT/SIGQUIT.

You can read about WCE (and about alternative approaches) here: [*Proper handling of SIGINT/SIGQUIT*](https://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html). The article is quite comprehensive. A short description of WCE from [Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/SignalTrap#Special_Note_On_SIGINT_and_SIGQUIT) is enough to get the idea:

> bash is among a few shells that implement a *wait and cooperative exit* approach at handling SIGINT/SIGQUIT delivery. When interpreting a script, upon receiving a SIGINT, it doesn't exit straight away but instead waits for the currently running command to return and only exits (by killing itself with SIGINT) if that command was also killed by that SIGINT. The idea is that if your script calls `vi` for instance, and you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> within `vi` to cancel an action, that should not be considered as a request to abort the script.

What does it mean for your script?

If `<pid>` is the PID of the script (i.e. the PID of `bash` interpreting the script) then your `kill -INT <pid>` sends SIGINT to this process only. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or `kill -INT -- -<pid>` ("negative" PID) would send SIGINT to the entire process group. SIGINT is by design the "interrupt from keyboard" (see `man 7 signal`), so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is the by-design way to send SIGINT, so sending SIGINT to the foreground process group (as opposed to sending to a *single* process) is the by-design usage of SIGINT.

When `bash` interpreting the script gets SIGINT while waiting for `sleep 1` to return, it handles the signal and reacts or not, depending on the reaction of `sleep`. In fact the shell cannot tell if `sleep` is also getting the signal; it assumes. The shell assumes the signal comes from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (or something equivalent) because this is the by-design usage of SIGINT; so the shell assumes the current `sleep` has also got the signal.

If `sleep` really got the signal (i.e. if you used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or `kill -INT -- -<pid>`) then it would be terminated because of the signal. In general a process is able to tell if its child was terminated by a signal, so here the shell would be able to tell that `sleep` was terminated by the signal. If `sleep` was terminated by SIGINT, the shell would conclude the user has pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in order to terminate the whole script, so the shell would kill itself with SIGINT (note: not just exit; it would kill itself by stopping handling the signal and sending the signal to itself, so if the parent of the shell also implemented WCE, then it would in turn react accordingly; and so on).

Your `sleep` had not got the signal, but `bash` interpreting the script assumed it had. Then the shell observed that `sleep` had exited nicely (not having been terminated by the signal), so it assumed `sleep` had *handled or ignored* the signal; so it assumed that yes, there had been <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but as a part of *normal* operation of the child, not as an attempt to terminate the whole script. This is why the shell did not exit, it continued interpreting the script as if nothing happened, because `sleep` had exited as if nothing happened.

In other words a parent implementing WCE reacts to SIGINT/SIGQUIT according to how the currently running child reacts. By sending SIGINT to `bash` and not sending to `sleep`, you kinda tricked the shell: you made it assume that `sleep` had handled or ignored the signal and everything is fine, thus exiting the whole script would be the Wrong Thing.

> I changed the `SIGINT` to a `SIGTERM` and it just abruptly killed the process without waiting

WCE is about handling SIGINT/SIGQUIT. There is no such mechanism (nor any need for it, I think) in case of SIGTERM, so this signal "just works".